# I have a MacBook Air currently running Windows 10 natively, but want to dual-boot OS X without wiping Windows. Is this possible?

Tags: macos, windows-10, multi-boot, macbook-air

My laptop is currently running Windows 10, and it was installed natively on a blank system. This resulted in the drive being partitioned using the Master Boot Record scheme, which OS X cannot install on. I want to know if it is possible to essentially do a backwards Boot Camp installation, where I can partition and install OS X on the new partition. I would rather not lose all of the data on the Windows install because I have spent several months setting it up exactly how I like it. Is there any way to do this short of backing up my data and wiping the SSD?

Comment: Due to Windows existing on a MBR partitioned HDD and OS X not supporting MBR you are out of luck.  You should always install Windows in such a way it can support GPT partitions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you've to Windows installed on a PC and want to dual boot a Mac with OSX and Windows while porting your current Win install. If this is correct, I'll assume that your target Mac already has a partition where Windows will be installed to. That said, there are a few ways to approach this problem. *Caveat Emptor:* I haven't touched Windows since Win8 came out so I can't guarantee that these will work with Win10.

1. **Forego dual boot and use Windows in a virtual machine.** Unless you can't deal with the performance limitations of a VM, I always recommend this above any other solution. After all, dual booting is ***so very 1990's***. Any decent VM ([VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html), [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) will work just fine. I've only used VMware's products so I know they have a built-in utility that would actually clone a PC into a VM. This is old technology for VMware. They've been doing this for years and are good at it. I've done it a few times in the past with Win7 and it's worked well. Plus you can run Windows and OSX side by side.
2. **Install Windows (unconfigured) on your target partition and use an Microsoft sanctioned utility to transfer your customizations and data.** I used to do this with the Windows Easy Transfer tool. I see now that this util is discontinued for Win10 but MS now has [PCmover Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/transfer-your-data) They partnered with Laplink on this so the underlying tech is solid. A potential drawback (owning from my experience with Easy Transfer) is that you may have to reinstall apps. Data and settings should come over with ease.
3. **Same as above but use a backup utility for the restore.** Restoring Windows to another system has traditionally been tricky on good days and painful on the average. It's theoretically feasible and it may work in Win10 but access to a seasoned Windows admin may be a good idea.

Whichever you choose, make sure to backup both machines before starting this endeavor and verify the backups are good.